# How to read in csv's using Python from a website with many csv's

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I restarted the project I was working on but the code I have says:

```
files=[file for file in os.listdir("https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/DL")]

print(files)
# for file in files:
#     df=pd.read_csv()
```

which gives me an error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/DL'
```

as I am wanting to see which csv's are officially in this website to help download the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir` is for viewing local directories, not remote over HTTPS
You need to download the files, you need to use something like [request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: That helps but how do I use it to see which csv's are on there

Comment: Can't help you with that because I get "Access Denied" Error when I try to enter the URLin the question.

Comment: Maybe try it without the /DL or does that still get access denied